# Downstream rate goes suddenly from 12000 kbps to 500-0 kbps- excellent line attenuation and snr margin

Tags: router, adsl

As the title says the line drops for hours or days to unworkable speeds or goes downright offline. I tried to change cables and filters but nothing changed. I should mention the phone also does not work anymore. I have ADSL2+ and my modem gives me excellent downstream snr margin (22.3 db) and attenuation(13.5db). Upstream rate is not as affected as it goes from 900 to 700 kbps.

Do you think the problem comes from the provider or from my flat? In case you think it′s my flat- is it the router or the phone/internet cables in the walls?

thank you.

Comment: As long as you have not broken it, the provider is probably responsible for getting the signals to an end point (the master socket in UK). Get them to fix it, or if you broke it, then pay them £20-£40 to fix it.

Comment: @richard You can post that as an answer yannow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you have not broken it, the provider is probably responsible for getting the signals to an end point (the master socket in UK). Get them to fix it, or if you broke it, then pay them £20-£40 to fix it